# WP Blocks save function doesn't match edit function when editor loads

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm developing a WP Gutenberg block based on https://github.com/JimSchofield/Guty-Blocks-2 and I'm running into an issue where the saved content doesn't match the editor when loaded therefore I'm seeing an error 'This block contains unexpected or invalid content'.

I have tried looking in the browser console but I can't figure out where the discrepancy is, both the edit and save functions reference the images but they're not being stored by the save function.

[image: Imgur]

It's worth noting that once the block is loaded for the first time, used and the post is saved it works correctly on the front-end. It's when you go back to the editor it doesn't work anymore.

```
import './__block__.view.scss';
import './__block__.editor.scss';

const {
    registerBlockType,
    getBlockDefaultClassName
} = wp.blocks;

const { 
    InspectorControls,
    MediaUpload
} = wp.editor;

const {
    Button
} = wp.components;

registerBlockType('__namespace__/__block__', {
    title: '__prettyname__(noCase)',
    icon: '__icon__',
    category: '__category__',

    attributes: {
        imgUrl: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: 'img',
        },
    },

    edit({ attributes, className, setAttributes }) {

        //Destructuring the images array attribute
        const {images = []} = attributes;

        // This removes an image from the gallery
        const removeImage = (removeImage) => {
            //filter the images
            const newImages = images.filter( (image) => {
                //If the current image is equal to removeImage the image will be returnd
                if(image.id != removeImage.id) {
                    return image;
                }
            });

            //Saves the new state
            setAttributes({
                images:newImages,
            })
        }

        //Displays the images
        const displayImages = (images) => {
            return (
                //Loops throug the images
                images.map( (image) => {
                    return (
                    <div className="gallery-item-container">
                            <img className='gallery-item' src={image.url} key={ images.id } />
                            <div className='remove-item' onClick={() => removeImage(image)}><span class="dashicons dashicons-trash"></span></div>
                            <div className='caption-text'>{image.caption[0]}</div>
                    </div>
                    )
                })

            )
        }

        //JSX to return
        return (
            <div>
                <MediaUpload
                    onSelect={(media) => {setAttributes({images: [...images, ...media]});}}
                    type="image"
                    multiple={true}
                    value={images}
                    render={({open}) => (
                        <Button className="select-images-button is-button is-default is-large" onClick={open}>
                            Add images
                        </Button>
                    )}
                />
                <br />
                <div class="modal__img">
                    <div class="flexslider">
                        <ul class="slides" data-total-slides={images.length}>{ displayImages(images) }</ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },

    save({attributes}) {
        // Destructuring the images array attribute
        const { images = [] } = attributes;

        // Displays the images
        const displayImages = (images) => {
            return (
                images.map( (image,index) => {
                    return (
                            <li><img
                                className='lazy'
                                key={images.id}
                                data-src={image.url}
                                data-slide-no={index}
                                data-caption={image.caption[0]}
                                alt={image.alt}
                                /></li>
                    )
                })
            )
        }

        //JSX to return
        return (
            <div class="modal__img">
                <div class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides" data-total-slides={images.length}>{ displayImages(images) }</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

    },
});
```

I expected the block to output the original HTML when back in the editor, but this behaviour does not work.

Comment: You need to make sure that the HTML structure returned by the `save` function is identical to the one saved to database by the `save` function.

Comment: Comparing both of the version helped me a lot to find errors like these and for comparing I uses the site https://diffchecker.com

Answer (score 3):

In both the save and edit function your are referencing images from the attributes prop. Yet, when you register your block and set up the attributes, you only have imageUrl as an attribute. This means images are never getting stored in the DB, and do not exist when you come back to edit.

Adding images as a attribute should fix this.

What you have

```
attributes: {
    imgUrl: {
        type: 'array',
        source: 'children',
        selector: 'img',
    },
},
```

What it should be

```
attributes: {
    images: {
        type: 'array',
        default: []
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing *props* instead of attributes in edit and save functions, and then simply use

```
var attributes = props.attributes;
```

For more reference read the code in these [examples](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/blob/master/05-recipe-card/block.js).